# Immigration Process for Released Prisoners

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I've been watching a few episodes of "Banged Up Abroad" on Nat Geo lately and the question occurred to me: if I enter a country as a 90-day-visa-free tourist, get arrested and sentenced to 2 years in prison, what is my status in the the country upon my release from prison?

I don't expect that this is the same in every country, but in general, is one subject to a deportation order until such time as they actually leave the country, or do they re-enter upon departure from the prison, or is the 90 day period suspended during incarceration?

I hope never to need to know this, but still...

Comment: Possibly more appropriate on Expats.SE if you narrow it down to a single country? :)

Comment: Usually the status would be "no longer welcome, to be deported as soon as possible." They might arrange the deportation directly from the out-processing in prison, perhaps after only part of the sentence is served.